# Http.Request - tracking of status code doesn't seem to work

Tags: angular

I want to upload files to a location and then display the list of successfully uploaded files. The upload part works pretty well, the listing part not so much.

I make an upload file request like so (myFiles is an array of myFile class) :

```
public qFile: myFile;
@ViewChild('file') fileSelector: ElementRef;
upload(files: any){

if(files.length === 0) return;

const formData = new FormData();

for (let file of files) 
  formData.append(file.name, file);

const uploadReq = new HttpRequest(
      'POST',
      'https://adddressofmyservice/uploadFiles',
      formData,
      {
        reportProgress: true
      }
    );

this.http.request(uploadReq).subscribe(
  event => {
    if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
      this.progress = Math.round((100 * event.loaded) / event.total!);
    else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
      this.fileSelector.nativeElement.value = '';
      if (event.status === 200) for (let file of files) {
        this.qFile.FileName = file.name;
        this.qFile.FileExtension = file.type;
        this.qFile.FileSize = file.size;
        this.myFiles.push(this.qFile);
      }
    }
  });
```

However nothing is getting added to the list.

There should be labels added based on this array, but it doesn't display anything:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let selectedItem of myFiles; let y = index">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <label id="UNIQUELABEL{{ y }}">{{ selectedItem.FileName }}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your code correctly entering the if condition `(event.type === HttpEventType.Response)` and then `(event.status === 200)`. Please verify if `myFiles` is properly populated.

Comment: @ashish.gd I do get a code 200 response from server, and the file gets uploaded. If I put the code outside of this statement, the table gets properly populated.

Comment: What do you mean by `outside of this statement` ?

Comment: @ashish.gd I mean if I put the table populating code outside of the if(event.status...) it executes well. So my question is basically "why is if(event.status === 200) not executing even though I get a code 200 resposne from server?"

Comment: The `if(event.status...)` condition seems to be missing the if block parenthesis. That could be an issue. I see the `for` loop immediately after the `if` condition.